# How to Stop the page loading in firefox programmatically?

Tags: firefox, selenium, web-crawler, ghostdriver

I am running several tests with WebDriver and Firefox.

I'm running into a problem with the following command:

`WebDriver.get(www.google.com);`

With this command, WebDriver blocks till the onload event is fired. While this can normally takes seconds, it can take hours on websites which never finish loading.

What I'd like to do is stop loading the page after a certain timeout, somehow simulating Firefox's stop button.

I first tried execute the following JS code every time that I tried loading a page:

```
var loadTimeout=setTimeout(\"window.stop();\", 10000);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, probably because :

> Because of the order in which scripts are loaded, the stop() method cannot stop the document in which it is contained from loading [1](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)

UPDATE 1: I tried to use SquidProxy in order to add connect and request timeouts, but the problem persisted.

One weird thing that I found today is that one web site that never stopped loading on my machine (FF3.6 - 4.0 and Mac Os 10.6.7) loaded normally on other browsers and/or computers.

UPDATE 2: The problem apparently can be solved by telling Firefox not to load images. hopefully, everything will work after that...

I wish WebDriver had a better Chrome driver in order to use it. Firefox is disappointing me every day!

UPDATE 3: Selenium 2.9 added a new feature to handle cases where the driver appears to hang. This can be used with `FirefoxProfile` as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("web");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "fast");
```

I'll post whether this works after I try it.

UPDATE 4: at the end none of the above methods worked. I end up "killing" the threads that are taking to long to finish. I am planing to try [Ghostdriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) which is a Remote WebDriver that uses PhantomJS as back-end. PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable, so i expect not to have the problems of a real browser such as firefox. For people that are not obligate to use firefox(crawling purposes) i will update with the results

UPDATE 5: Time for an update. Using for 5 months the ghostdriver 1.1 instead FirefoxDriver i can say that i am really happy with his performance and stability. I got some cases where we have not the appropriate behaviour but looks like in general ghostdriver is stable enough. So if you need, like me, a browser for crawling/web scraping purposes  i recomend you use ghostdriver instead firefox and xvfb which will give you several headaches...

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. I end up "killing" the threads that got a non stoped loading page..

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get around this doing a few things.

First, set a timeout for the webdriver.  E.g.,

```
WebDriver wd;
... initialize wd ...
wd.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Second, when doing your get, wrap it around a TimeoutException.  (I added a UnhandledAlertException catch there just for good measure.) E.g.,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
        wd.get(url);
        break;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException te) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)wd).executeScript("window.stop();");
    } catch (UnhandledAlertException uae) {
        Alert alert = wd.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
 }
```

This basically tries to load the page, but if it times out, it forces the page to stop loading via javascript, then tries to get the page again.  It might not help in your case, but it definitely helped in mine, particularly when doing a webdriver's `getCurrentUrl()` command, which can also take too long, have an alert, and require the page to stop loading before you get the url.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Looks legit. i am gonna try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem, and there's no general solution it seems. There is, however, a bug about it in their bug tracking system which you could 'star' to vote for it.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=687

One of the comments on that bug has a workaround which may work for you - Basically, it creates a separate thread which waits for the required time, and then tries to simulate pressing escape in the browser, but that requires the browser window to be frontmost, which may be a problem.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=687#c4

Comment: Yep..i already tried this also..no luck because of the paralelization of the tests...i am wondering if someone from WebDriver or Firefox will do something for that..

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to use this class:
`WebDriverBackedSelenium`;

```
//When creating a new browser:
WebDriver driver = _initBrowser(); //Just returns firefox WebDriver
WebDriverBackedSelenium backedSelenuium = 
            new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,"about:blank");    

//This code has to be put where a TimeOut is detected
//I use ExecutorService and Future<?> Object

void onTimeOut()
{
    backedSelenuium.runScript("window.stop();");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a ruby compatible solution for the same? I got stuck this area.

Answer (score 1):

It was a really tedious issue to solve. However, I am wondering why people are complicating it. I just did the following and the problem got resolved (perhaps got supported recently):

```
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
driver.get('somewebpage')
```

It worked for me using *Firefox* driver (and *Chrome* driver as well).

Answer (score 0):

> One weird thing that i found today is that one web site that never stop loading on my machine (FF3.6 - 4.0 and Mac Os 10.6.7), is stop loading NORMALy in Chrome in my machine and also in another Mac Os and Windows machines of some colleague of mine!

I think the problem is closely related to Firefox bugs. See [this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1336-FireFox-Never-Stops-Loading-With-iFrame-Submission.htm) for details. Maybe upgrade of FireFox to the latest version will solve your problem. Anyway I wish to see Selenium update that simulates the "stop" button...

Answer (score 0):

Basically I set the browser timeout lower than my selenium hub, and then catch the error. And then stop the browser from loading, then continue the test.

```js
webdriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(55000);

function handleError(err){
          console.log(err.stack);
        };


return webdriver.get(url).then(null,handleError).then(function () {
            return webdriver.executeScript("return window.stop()");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , the following concept worked with me on Chrome , try the same:

1) Navigate to "about:blank"
2) get element "body"
3) on the elemënt , just Send Keys Ësc

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone else might be stuck with the same forever loading annoyance, you can use simple add-ons such as [Killspinners for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/killspinners/) to do the job effortlessly.

Edit : This solution doesn't work if javascript is the problem. Then you could go for a Greasemonkey script such as :

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        auto kill
// @namespace   default
// @description auto kill
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function sleep1() {
  window.stop();
  setTimeout(sleep1, 1500);
}

setTimeout(sleep1, 5000);
```