# Selenium Webdriver Continuing After Site from get() Prompts for Cert

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I'm writing a Java app in which I'm doing a simple `driver.get(url)` in which the url will prompt for a cert selection.  I want to try and automate the cert selection process in Firefox 33 using the AutoIt jar, but I can't even get my Java program to continue after it executes this `get`, since the site is in an indefinite state of loading until a cert is selected, so the execution indefinitely stays on the `get` itself.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question: [Make Selenium Webdriver Stop Loading the page if the desired element is already loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214340/make-selenium-webdriver-stop-loading-the-page-if-the-desired-element-is-already)

Ths solution given in the above link is to change the firefox settings in case the webpage is taking too long to load.

```
FirefoxBinary firefox = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/path/to/firefox.exe"));
FirefoxProfile customProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
customProfile.setPreference("network.http.connection-timeout", 10);
customProfile.setPreference("network.http.connection-retry-timeout", 10);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox, customProfile);
```